# How to only pass an optional parameter to a PHP function by keeping all other mandatory/optional parameters(if any) equal to their default values?

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

I'm using **PHP 7.3.2** on my laptop that runs **on Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system**.

I've installed the latest version of **XAMPP** installer on my laptop which has installed the **Apache/2.4.38 (Win32)** and **PHP 7.3.2**

Please do consider below prototype definition of the built-in PHP function `htmlspecialchars()` from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-description):

```
htmlspecialchars ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = TRUE ]]] ) : string
```

Now, I only want to set the last optional parameter i.e. `$double_encode` with a **boolean value** `FALSE` and keep all other optional parameters set to their default values.

For achieving this I tried below code :

```
<?php
  echo htmlspecialchars('&amp', '', '', FALSE);
?>
```

After executing the above code I got following output in my web browser :

```
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given in th67i.php on line 2
```

I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong. I took care of other parameters to be set to their default values by keeping blank spaces separated by commas and only assigning the optional parameter `$double_encode` to **boolean value** `FALSE`.

Then why I'm not able to get the output and getting some warning? Why? What mistake I'm making in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `''` does not mean falling back to default argument value. It means just that — trying to pass an empty string.

You would need to reproduce defaults if you want to achieve this:

```php
htmlspecialchars('&amp', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, ini_get('default_charset'), FALSE);
```

Comment: If such is the case then why I'm getting the same output upon setting the optional parameter `double_encode` to `FALSE` and `TRUE`. The results should have to be different for the value `TRUE` and for the value `FALSE`. **Why it's not happening then?** In both cases I'm getting the same output as `&amp;amp`

Comment: For your specific example this argument is irrelevant. You might observe the difference if you use `&amp;` (your string misses `;`).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I missed the semicolon at the end. Thanks for your help bro.

Comment: Do I need to reproduce all the remaining defaults whenever I want to pass a customized optional argument or more than one customized arguments? If yes, then let me know is this applicable to only built-in PHP functions or to both the user-defined and built-in PHP functions? Thank You.

Comment: You have to reproduce anything _before_ your customized arguments, anything _after_ will fall back to defaults natively. For user defined function the behavior is up to implementation, but generally you will have to fill in preceding defaults as well.